# Apache airflow - Unable to templatize queue name inherited from baseOperator

Tags: jinja2, airflow

I have a Custom operator that inherits `baseoperator`. I am trying to templatize 'queue' name so that task can be picked up by different Celery worker.

But it uses raw template string (un rendered jinja string) as the queue name instead of rendered string.

The same flow works if I give the intended queue name directly as a simple string.

```
from airflow import DAG
from operators.check_operator import CheckQueueOperator
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from airflow.operators.python_operator import BranchPythonOperator
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago

default_args = {
    'schedule_interval': None,  # exclusively “externally triggered” DAG
    'owner': 'admin',
    'description': 'This helps to quickly check queue templatization',
    'start_date': days_ago(1),
    'retries': 0,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5),
    'provide_context': True
}


# this goes to wrong queue --> {{ dag_run.conf["queue"]}}
with DAG('test_queue', default_args=default_args) as dag:
    t1 = CheckQueueOperator(task_id='check_q',
        queue='{{ dag_run.conf["queue"]}}'
    )
```

In the above this scenario :

- In RabbitMQ, I see the task being queued under queue name '{{ dag_run.conf["queue"]}}' (raw template string )
- In Airflow, under `Rendered template` I am able to see properly rendered value for `queue` field
- In the screenshot, we see `docker-desktop` as queue name. It's my test queue and also my default airflow queue. It works perfectly if I give this queue name as a direct string.

[image]

```
#this goes to right queue --> my_target_queue
with DAG('test_queue', default_args=default_args) as dag:
    t1 = CheckQueueOperator(task_id='check_q',
        queue='my_target_queue'
    )
```

CheckQueueOperator code :

```
from airflow.models.baseoperator import BaseOperator
from airflow.models import BaseOperator
from airflow.utils.decorators import apply_defaults

'''
Validate if queue can be templatized in base operator
'''
class CheckQueueOperator(BaseOperator):
    template_fields = ['queue']

    @apply_defaults
    def __init__(
        self,
        *args,
        **kwargs
    ):
        super(CheckQueueOperator, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def execute(self, context):
        self.log.info('*******************************')
        self.log.info('Queue name %s', self.queue)
        return
```

Stack details:

- Apache Airflow version - 1.10.12
- Using CeleryExecutor
- Using RabbitMQ

Answer (score 0):

The `queue` attribute is reserved (*perhaps not officially, but in practice*) by the `BaseOperator` and while you may be able to hoodwink the webserver into rendering the attribute, the parts of Airflow that handle scheduling and task execution *don't perform rendering* prior to reading the `queue` attribute.